# ValueInjecter - converting some properties of source into a list in target

Tags: automapper, valueinjecter

Just started using Value Injector: http://valueinjecter.codeplex.com/, and I have a question:

I have a Source class that has many properties. Some properties have a common suffix of "Profile". These properties are not always String, but mostly are. Target has 1 property, `Dictionary<string, string>`. I would like all properties that end with "Profile" to be inserted into the `Dictionary<string, string>` with key = PropertyName and value = Property's value. I think it can be done but the documentation isn't very clear to me. Can someone point me to the right direction? Thanks!

Comment: [AutoMapper](https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper) is also a mapping utility. Are you also asking if it can be done in AutoMapper, or is this incorrectly tagged? Thx.

Comment: @Mightymuke I guess he would accept an answer using automapper as well

Comment: @Echiban and what's the target dictionary property name ? /name convention

Answer (score 1):

Sorry I have no experience with Value Injector, but if you chose to use [AutoMapper](https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper/wiki) you would most likely use a [Custom Resolver](https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper/wiki/Custom-value-resolvers):

```cs
Mapper.CreateMap<Source, Destination>()
    .ForMember(dest => dest.Profile, opt => opt.ResolveUsing<ProfileResolver>());
```

Where the resolver would look something like:

```cs
public class ProfileResolver : ValueResolver<Source, Dictionary<string, string>>
{
    protected override int ResolveCore(Source source)
    {
        var rc = new Dictionary<string, string>();
        // Do some funky reflection stuff here
        return rc;
    }
```

}

Full details can be found in the [custom resolver documentation](https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper/wiki/Custom-value-resolvers).